# A question on faithful representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

So, I am learning representation theory using Bruce Sagan's book and I am stuck at one of the exercises that I attempted:

If $X$ is a matrix representation of a group $G$, then its kernel is the
set $N = \left\{g \in G : X(g) = J\right\}$. A representation is faithful if it is one-to-one. I have four questions about this:

(a) Show that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and find a condition on
$N$ equivalent to the representation being faithful.

(b) Suppose $X$ has character $\chi$ and degree $d$. Prove that $g \in N$ if and only if $\chi(g) =d$. Hint: Show that $\chi(g)$ is a sum of roots of unity.

(c) Show that for the coset representation $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G(1)$, one has $N = \bigcap_i g_iHg_i^{-1} $, where the $g_i$ are the transversal.

(d) For each of the following representations, under what conditions
are they faithful: trivial, regular, coset, sign for $S_n$, defining for
$S_n$, degree 1 for $C_n$?

I am not a mathematician, so I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Most users here aren't mathematicians!

Answer (score 0):

For (a) look at what $X(n), n\in N$ can be under Schur's lemma for irreducible representations.

For (b) use the given hint along with triangle inequality.(especially the condition  when equality holds). (i.e $|\sum_j z_j | \leq \sum_j |z_j|$

Your question (c) is not clear (what are $N$ and $H$ what is the relation between them?)

For (d)  trivial and sign representation of $S_n$ should be easy looking at the orders of the group and comparing it with the order of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(a) Kernels of group morphisms are always normal subgroups,

(b) Diagonalising the action of $g$, you've got $d$ diagonal entries, all roots of unity, and $\chi(g)$ is their sum.

(c) In the usual construction of $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G(1)$ as $\bigoplus_ig_i1$, the stabiliser subgroup of the $1$-dimensional subspace $g_i1$ is $g_iHg_i^{-1}$.